# tibco-rv inbound outbound messages

Tags: tibco-rv

I work as a working student and we use the tibco rv bussystem for messages between our 5 servers. My question is, what exactly are outbound and inbound messages? In the tib_rv_concepts.pdf it says, that outbound messages are transmitted from program processes to the network and inbound messages the other way around. But what exactly does that mean? For me, it seems as if the outbound messages are just the messages that are going out from the daemon on the bus and inbound messages are the ones, that are taken from the bus.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  When your process sends a message, it's an outbound message for your process.  It's inbound when it comes in.